# Render json with a condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I am working on serializers. I want to display some jobs with attribute `cancelled=true`. I tried `render json: @jobs, :only => [:cancelled]`, but its only displaying the jobs with cancelled attribute. How can I filter the jobs? I also tried `json: @jobs, :only => [:cancelled =="true"]`, but it's not working.

I tried it in serializer too. This is my serializer:

```
module V1
  module Jobs
    class CancelledJobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attribute :id, if: :id?
      attribute :cancelled, if: :cancelled?
      def cancelled?
        true if object.cancelled
      end
      def id?
        true if object.cancelled
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and it returns

```
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{"cancelled":true }
```

Is there anyway to remove those parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a scope to the `Job` model so it can return canceled (cancelled) jobs

```
scope :cancelled, -> { where(cancelled: true) }
```

And then in your controller

```
@cancelled_jobs = Job.cancelled
render json: @cancelled_jobs
```